# Check if a database cell is empty first

Tags: c#, ms-access, exception, oledb

I am accessing an MS Access 2007 database through C#, and I keep getting an exception whenever I try to read an empty cell.

Specifically, I am trying to read a "Date/Time" cell that may or may not be empty.
I am using [OLE DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB), and have filled a DataSet.  None of these conditions work:

```
DataSet dataSet = GetDataSet();
DataRow row = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
DateTime time = new DateTime();
time = (DateTime)row[5];   // Exception thrown
```

How to check if the cell is empty before trying to assign it?  None of these work:

```
if(row[5] == null) ;
if(row[5] == DBNull) ;
if(row[5] == (String)"") ;
```

Edit: I should have mentioned: When I debug, it says that row[5] equals "System.DBNull,", but I get an error when I try "if(row[5] == DBNULL)".  The error says "DBNULL is a type, which is not valid in the given context".

Comment: "cell" is what you reference in a spreadsheet; it's a specific column in a record when dealing with a database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check it like the following.

```
if (row[5] == DBNull.Value)
{
    // value is null
}
else if (String.IsNullOfEmpty(Convert.ToString(row[5]))
{
    // value is still null
}
else
{
    // value is not null here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  I didn't put the ".Value" after DBNULL.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(row[5] == DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's it. Forgot the ".Value"

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Convert.IsDBNull(row[5]))
{
...
}
```